# Facebook login with sdk php

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm a french student so, sorry for my bad English. I develop with Facebook sdk js and sdk php.

I had a login problem during about 10 months. Some of people couldn't access to my app or needed to reload the page. Now, I'm trying the new Facebook sdk 4.0 but that's not better, i probably forgot something.

Actually, sometimes i can access to my app directly, sometimes i have an error and i just need to reload, and sometimes i can't access to my app although i reload. That's very aleatory.

I show you a screen of the error i have when i print_r on a FacebookRequestException when i try to have a `$session ($session = $helper->getSession();)`.

[Error message](http://hpics.li/69e10c8)

That's how i use the Facebook sdk php :

```
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;

session_start();

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('***','***');
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();


if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {

  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $session = null;
  }

} else {

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        print_r($ex);
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        print_r($ex);
    }
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {


  $access_token = $session->getToken(); 
  $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, '***'); 

  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me', array("appsecret_proof" =>  $appsecret_proof) ); 
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
  $GLOBALS["facebook"]["joueur"] = $graphObject; 



  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends', array("appsecret_proof" =>  $appsecret_proof) );
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
  $GLOBALS["facebook"]["amis"] = $graphObject->asArray()["data"]; 

}
```

Thank you to try to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and after a lot of hours of search, I removed all the php sdk. I can recolte all information about the user by the js sdk, and use ajax for access to my bdd. During all of this process, I load all my js files and when I receive the php data, i call some functions for fill the div.

Answer (score 0):

That is a heavy load of require statements, why not just use the autoloader instead?

Anyway, this is how it works:

- Use FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper to get a session
- Get the Access Token from the session
- Store the Access Token in your own session
- Use the Access Token for all future API calls

An example with full code can be found here: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

Comment: I'm agree with you, i replaced all my require_once by require_once( 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );

I used this line $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken(); 
Now i have a better stability when i can reach my app.

But i have again 2 problem to solve when i try to have the first access :
- I have a FacebookRequestException when i try this line : $session = $helper->getSession();
- Sometimes i have no exeption but when i do if ( isset( $session ) ) I can see i have nothing in the $session